# ¿Como puedo lograr no abrir dos veces la misma ventana wpf en c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una aplicación base pero la ventana secundaria no se debería abrir dos veces cuando haga click en el menú.

Este es mi código:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   {

    Agregar_Vendedor ventana_agregar_vendedor = new Agregar_Vendedor();

    ventana_agregar_vendedor.Show();

}
```

No sé como lograr que no se abra si ya está creada.

Comment: Hola @Elias. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor, agrega el código comentando en qué punto se está abriendo dos veces, para poder contextualizar tu pregunta. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: http://pastebin.com/w8FZUnAJ @Mariano no he podido lograr que la ventana no se abra nuevamente si ya esta corriendo

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es abrir una ventana secundaria y que no se pueda volver a la ventana principal a menos que se cierre esta segunda ventana, puedes probar con el método ShowDialog:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   {

    Agregar_Vendedor ventana_agregar_vendedor = new Agregar_Vendedor();

    ventana_agregar_vendedor.ShowDialog();

}
```

Si no, lo que puedes hacer es inhabilitar el menú que abre la ventana cuando se muestra:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   {

    Agregar_Vendedor ventana_agregar_vendedor = new Agregar_Vendedor();

    ventana_agregar_vendedor.ShowDialog();

    MenuItem.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Lo que deberías hacer después, es volver a activar MenuItem cuando se cierre la segunda ventana.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @Jose Antonio Bautista me parece la más sencilla y correcta. De todas maneras, ten en cuenta que en WPF puedes saber qué ventanas están activas a través de la colección `Application.Current.Windows`. Así, si por el motivo que fuera no quisieras/pudieras utilizar el método `ShowDialog()`, antes de crear una nueva instancia de `Agregar_Vendedor` podrías mirar si no se encuentra ya en esa colección.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Agregar_Vendedor>().Count() == 0)
    {
        Agregar_Vendedor ventana_agregar_vendedor = new Agregar_Vendedor();
        ventana_agregar_vendedor.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy sencillo, puedes lograrlo con este tip:

Lo primero es declara tu ventana como una variable de clase, sin inicializar:

```
private Agregar_Vendedor ventana_agregar_vendedor;
```

ó como propiedad si deseas, es más elegante:

```
private Agregar_Vendedor _ventana_agregar_vendedor;
public Agregar_Vendedor Ventana_agregar_vendedor
{
    get { return _ventana_agregar_vendedor; }
    set { _ventana_agregar_vendedor = value; }
}
```

Luego cuando necesites abrirla, lo haces de este modo:

```
if (ventana_agregar_vendedor == null)
{
    ventana_agregar_vendedor = new Agregar_Vendedor();
    ventana_agregar_vendedor.Closed += (a, b) => ventana_agregar_vendedor = null;
    ventana_agregar_vendedor.Show();
}
else
{
    ventana_agregar_vendedor.Show();                    
}
```

Y listo.

Answer (score 0):

a lo mejor este post es de hace mucho  pero de seguro hay varios estudiantes etc.. que no saben la solucion de esto simplificado y escrito en c++ seria la solucion asi pueden traducirlo muy facil a c#

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim objForm2 As Form2

  Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    If objForm2 Is Nothing OrElse Not objForm2.Visible Then
      objForm2 = New Form2
    End If
    objForm2.Show()
    objForm2.Focus()
  End Sub
End Class
```

pueden poner un

```
objForm2.BringToFront()
```

como plus

Comment: El usuario pide la respuesta específica en **C#**, también intenta siempre agregar la explicación respectiva de lo que hace tu código, las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). ;)